# Vectorizing a positionally reliant function in NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I understand the concept of vectorization, and how you can avoid using a loop to run through the elements when you want to adjust each individual element, however what I can't figure out it how to do this when we have a conditional based on the neighbouring values of a pixel.

For example, if I have a mask:

```
mask = np.array([[0,0,0,0],
                 [1,0,0,0],
                 [0,0,0,1], 
                 [1,0,0,0]])
```

And I wanted to change an element by evaluating neighboring components in the mask, like so:

```
if sum(mask[j-1:j+2,i-1:i+2].flatten())>1 and mask[j,i]!=1:
    out[j,i]=1
```

How can I vectorize the operation when I specifically need to access the neighboring elements?

Thanks in advance.

Full loop:

```
import numpy as np

mask = np.array([[0,0,0,0], [1,0,0,0], [0,0,0,1],  [1,0,0,0]])
out = np.zeros(mask.shape)
for j in range(len(mask)):
    for i in range(len(mask[0])):
        if sum(mask[j-1:j+2,i-1:i+2].flatten())>1 and mask[j,i]!=1:
            out[j,i]=1
```

Output:

```
[[0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

Comment: Are you sure of your indexing? if i == 0 then i-1 = -1. The negative indexing does not give you a neighborhood element.

Comment: btw, `sum(mask[j-1:j+2,i-1:i+2].flatten())>1` should just be `mask[j-1:j+2,i-1:i+2].sum() > 1`

Comment: @Corralien That is true, in the actual work I am not considering edge effects, however you are correct using a -1 index would return the element from the other end of the array.

Comment: I think `mask[j,i]!=1` is useless. If 1, the value of `out[j,i]` is already 1 and if not set `out[j,i]` to 1. At the end if `sum(mask[j-1:j+2,i-1:i+2].flatten())>1`, `out[j,i]` should be 1. So the first condition only is sufficient.

Comment: @Corralien this isn't true as if you image a mask of all 1's then every value in the output would also be one without this condition implimented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a 'neighborhood sum' operation is often called a 2D *convolution*. In your case since you don't have any weighting it is efficiently implemented in the (IMO somewhat poorly named) [`scipy.ndimage.uniform_filter`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.uniform_filter.html), which can compute the mean of a neighborhood (and the sum is
just the mean multiplied by the size).

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage import uniform_filter

mask = np.array([[0,0,0,0], [1,0,0,0], [0,0,0,1], [1,0,0,0]])
neighbor_sum = 9 * uniform_filter(mask.astype(np.float32), 3, mode="constant")
neighbor_sum = np.rint(neighbor_sum).astype(int)
out = ((neighbor_sum > 1) & (mask != 1)).astype(int)
print(out)
```

Output (which is different than your example but looking at it by hand is correct, assuming you don't want the edges to wrap around):

```
[[0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0]
 [1 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0]]
```

If you do want the edges to wrap around (or other edge behavior), look at the `mode` argument of `uniform_filter`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. This does indeed have the correct output (just looking by eye) as my code didn't correctly evaluate the edges. There is also roughly a 2x speed boost comparative to my method. Not that I am opposed to using scipy, but is there a way to achieve this specifically with NumPy?

Comment: _"There is also roughly a 2x speed boost comparative to my method."_ Maybe for only a tiny 4 by 4 image. I can't imagine this not being *much* faster than your original method for larger images. "Not that I am opposed to using scipy, but is there a way to achieve this specifically with NumPy?" You can, but it's annoying. `scipy` and `numpy` often go hand in hand, and `uniform_filter` does *exactly* what you want, so I would strongly suggest to just use that.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Both your points are correct, with the latter I was asking out of curiosity more than necessity. Thanks for the help!